# "'Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected" or not getting any info with urllib3 and Django

Tags: python, django, python-requests, screen-scraping, urllib3

I am developing a web scraping application with BeautifulSoup and Django and I am experiencing some 'conexion issues' (I think).

The app has to check if any website is satisfying all the SEO requirements, and for that, I have to make different 'requests'... first to get the "soup" and then to check if the robots.txt and sitemap.xml, for example, exists... so I guess some sites are blocking my app because of that, and I keep getting the "'Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected" error or in other cases, I don't get the error but the "soup" is empty... is there a way to fix this? I have tried with `time.sleep()` but doesn't seem to work...

This is part of my code:

```
 http = PoolManager()
 r = http.request('GET', "https://" + url, headers={'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36", 'Accept-Encoding': 'br'})
    
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.data, 'lxml')
```

And where I check if robots and sitemap exists:

```
robots_url = url + "/robots.txt"
robot = requests.get(robots_url, headers)

if robot.ok:
    robot = True
else:
    robot = False

sleep(5)

sitemap_url = url + '/sitemap.xml'
sitemap = requests.get(sitemap_url, headers=headers)
if sitemap.ok:
    sitemap = True
else:
    sitemap = False
```

In most websites the code is working fine but there are some pages that I supposed have a higher security level that ends the connection with that error:

```
During handling of the above exception (('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))), another exception occurred:
```

/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner

Thank you so much in advance for your time and advice.

Comment: is it happening with only certain website or for all?

Comment: Hello! I had this issue just with 3-5 websites and I tested like 50, but I would need to find a solution because they will be testing all kind of websites at my company with this. Thanks for answering :)